# Creating Views like Django Admin Panel

Tags: django, view

is there any way to create views like the ones shown on Admin Panel without any effort, I mean, generic views that display all the fields and have the ability to add foreign key items and such, just like admin panel?

I've tried using

> django.views.generic.edit.FormView
>
> django.views.generic.edit.CreateView
>
> django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView
>
> django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView

But I am forced to specify fields, and I have quite a lot. It also doesn't allow me to create objects for the foreignkey fields if there's any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried with extending the template from default admin? an example `{% extends "admin:admin/index.html" %}`

Comment: You are not forced to specify fields. You need to set the model property in generic views and render the form with a simple p tag.

Comment: I'll extend the admin panel then! Thanks for your answer.

I am forced to specify fields on the views.py though.